# Migrate Android app from Native to React Native

Tags: java, android, firebase, react-native

I'm currently working on an android app that's based on Java with Firebase in the backend. Is there any way to migrate to React Native without building it from scratch?

Comment: The approach you're looking for is "Brownfield" - having native application hosting React Native screens

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks.